# Removing characters and renaming files

Tags: python, rename, batch-rename

Having trouble shortening to the first 13 characters of a file name, any suggestions?

```
import os

path = '/home/ben/Desktop/UK_DDV'
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in files:
    outfile = file[:13]
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, outfile), os.path.join(path, outfile)+'.tif')
```

Keeping getting the error

> 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'

Comment: why are you slicing the filename?  If you are shortening the filename then of course it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `os.rename()` should be using the original filename, `file` instead of `outfile`.